# Do multiple hits with Touch of Idiocy stack ability damage?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Do multiple hits with [Touch of Idiocy](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/touchOfIdiocy.htm) stack ability damage? If not do you just count the hit with the highest damage? Checked this in several discussion forums and found conflicting answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Simply:** They don't stack, apply only the highest penality.

**Detailed:** As it says in [the basic rules section of the srd](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm), modifiers to a given check or roll stack if they come from different sources and have different types, but *do not stack if they have the same type or come from the same source (such as the same spell cast twice in succession)*.

Since touch of idiocy applies a penalty, this penalty will not stack with another touch of idiocy penalty.

Answer (score 11):

## It does not stack

It would stack *if* it were ability damage, but it isn't. [It's a penalty](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/touchOfIdiocy.htm):

> Your successful melee touch attack applies **a 1d6 penalty** to the target’s Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores.

[Penalties from the same source do not stack](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm#stacking), so only the highest penalty will be applied.

Comment: Touch of Idiocy is a bit of a bad case. The Sor/Wiz level 2 spell list says it deals ability damage, while the actual spell description says penalty. The real description has more weight, but the discrepancy is enough to confuse tables (and the internet).